# Wifi gets disconnected every now and then, fails to reconnect

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 17.04

I'm using ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome Desktop.

Since a few days, my Wifi disconnects periodically.

Here is a log of NetworkManager's behavior: https://pastebin.com/raw/2h69B4iS

At 09:26, I am connected.
At 11:56, the connection is lost and NetWorkManager fails to reconnect.
At 14:23, I disable the adapter via NetworkManager, re-enable it and the connection is back within less than 10 seconds.

After the connection is lost, NetworkManager also fails to detect any Wifi network. To restore functionality, I have to turn it off and on again.

Comment: Maybe hardware issue. Did you see any related message to your wifi device in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: I don't see how a hardware issue could manifest in such a specific problem. 

Regarding syslog - Nothing unusual here. As described, unless a disconnect occurs, everything is working fine.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and edit the question to post your results.  You can also use paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL